# How to do UI Virtualization when GridView width set to Auto

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8.1

I have around 1000 items which I need to display in a GridView, but UI do not response for a while as It tries to create all 1000 items at a time, so Is there any way that I can virtualize Gridview,

I read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx) msdn article and also tried custom wrappanel as metioned over  [here](http://codepaste.net/8gr5go), but nothing helped much.

Could anybody suggest me to do UI Virtualization for GridView Correctly.